# Authlib's Azure login throws an invalid_claim: Invalid claim "iss"

Tags: azure, authlib, starlette

I am currently login with Google with no problems, using Authlib for my Starlette app, but Azure throws this invalid claim "iss" error when doing:

```
await client.parse_id_token(request, token)
```

Please, any help will be wonderful. Googling it I didn't found anything.

The complete code snippet its:

```
async def do_azure_login(request: Request) -> Any:
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('authz_azure').replace(' ', '')
    azure = OAUTH.create_client('azure')
    return await azure.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

async def authz_azure(request: Request) -> HTMLResponse:
    return await authz(request, OAUTH.azure)

async def authz(request: Request, client: OAuth) -> HTMLResponse:
    token = await client.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = dict(await client.parse_id_token(request, token))

    request.session['username'] = user['email']
    request.session['first_name'] = user.get('given_name', '')
    request.session['last_name'] = user.get('family_name', '')

    response = TEMPLATING_ENGINE.TemplateResponse(
        name='app.html',
        context={
            'request': request
        }
    )
    return response
```

I think the problem may be in using those:

```
AZURE_CONF_URL = (
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
)
AZURE_AUTHZ_URL = (
    'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize'
)
```

Problem should be this "issuer":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0" placed in the AZURE_CONF_URL link. I've seen people having this same issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider posting a bit more of the relevant code.  As is, your code doesn't have any 'iss' mentioned but I suspect that's part of how you build your request.

Comment: How have you configured Authlib?

Comment: I added the most relevant parts. I think though the key is the final part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still researching. This may be useful.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/38427
https://github.com/authlib/loginpass/issues/65